# Responsive navbar with Bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I´m using Bootstrap 2.3.2 in my website. I´m trying to make to 100% responsive (it´s like 70%), so, I would like to use a navbar to collapse in small resolutions.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div>
                <a class="brand" href="/{{locationService.getLangKey()}}" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="img/logo.png" /><span class="logo">yanpy</span></a>               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8 pull-right" style="padding-right: 10px">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner custom-navbar-inner">  
                    <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 2: Place all navbar contents you want collapsed withing .navbar-collapse.collapse. -->
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="padding-top: 4px">                   
                        <!--<div ng-include src="'partials/login.html'"></div>-->                     
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar -->
        </div> <!-- span8 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the span4 and span8 are not working properly in 480px width. I don´t know why span4 is taking the whole row width.

Answer (score 0):

This version of bootstrap, spans below:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
```

default to 100% width. You will have to remove the below style for the spans to work below this screen width. You need to find the below and remove the width:100% line.

```
    @media (max-width: 767px)
[class*="span"], .uneditable-input[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: But is this a bug? Or it has a purpose. Should I update the bootstrap original css file. I think better overwrite the style, right?

Comment: Unfortunately you wont be able to "update" your bootstrap as the classes have now changed e.g. Span4 is now xs-col-4. Its not a bug. New bootstrap allows for %'s to work across all widths and can change at different breakpoints where you see fit. You will need to overwrite the style or amend the original file. Amending the file and removing the line will be easiest way